# ADF/JavaScript - Get bean variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I'm trying to recovery a bean value in JavaScript according to the source element:

```
function getValue(actionEvent){
    actionEvent.cancel();
    var component=actionEvent.getSource();
    var id=component.getId();
    var substr= id.substr(2,4); //This gives me "l11" for a component
    //Now I need the value of the bean variable MyBean.value<substr>
    //For this case, I need the value MyBean.valuel11
    //If I do something like alert("#{MyBean.valuel11}"); it works
    //But I need dynamically
    var val =   "#\{Main.value" + substr + "\}";
    alert(val);
}
```

But the result is showing:

## {MyBean.valuel11}, and not the bean value.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I received help from Oracle community.
The answer is to use clientAttribute

[Documentation for clientAttribute](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/1-2011-javascript-302460.pdf)

[Oracle Community Answer](https://community.oracle.com/message/13216996#13216996)